# Parent menu item does not display posts when I add the sub-items

Tags: posts, menus, pages

I have created 3 categories; Europe (as a parent category) and then I have two sub-categories Croatia and Wales.

In Dashboard > Appearance > Menu I when I only add the category Europe as a menu item, all posts tagged with this category are shown correctly.

[image: Europe item will show posts when it is like this]

However, when I then add the two sub-categories underneath it (to effectively create a drop down) the page Europe will not show any posts.

[image: Europe menu item wont load any posts on the page when structured like this]

Why is this happening and is it possible to fix via the admin panel?

Comment: Can you, please, edit your question to make it readable.

Comment: You mean posts are not being shown where? Give an example, maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: @filipecsweb on the website. Do the screenshots help now?

Answer (score 0):

First, really stupid question: Do you save your new menu after making the changes? Sometimes it's the little things that mess everything up.

Aside from that, it might be a theme problem. Change to one of WordPress default themes (Twenty XYZ series) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Of course I am saving it! It just doesn’t seem to load the posts for some reason. Which is very strange.

Comment: Have you tried switching themes?